# XSLT how to process multiple XML text nodes interspersed with other XML elements

Tags: xslt

When an element contains other elements interspersed with text, how to maintain the order of the text elements?  In this (simplified) example:

```
  <block>1st text<bsub>2nd text</bsub>3rd text</block>
```

the desired output is:

```
  "1st text 2nd text 3rd text"
```

I have tried:

```
  <xsl:template match="block">
    <xsl:value-of select=".">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="bsub"/>
    <xsl:value-of select=".">
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bsub">  
    <xsl:value-of select=".">
  </xsl:template>
```

and that outputs:

```
  "1st text 2nd text 3rd text 2nd text 1st text 2nd text 3rd text"
```

How to select the individual text elements (of `<block>`) using `<xsl:value-of>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use value-of for processing mixed content like this - use apply-templates instead and it will all work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <t>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </t>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block|bsub">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...when applied to your input document...

```
<block>1st text<bsub>2nd text</bsub>3rd text</block>
```

...yields...

```
<t>1st text 2nd text 3rd text </t>
```